# Library module dependency Vs App module dependencies

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I have made many tiny projects so far such as single screen, quiz app, musical structure etc... As a newbie, I was looking for reusability of project as there are many packages those are same in all projects such as utils etc... So, I came to know about Android library module from below link:

https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library

My problem is, even after adding dependencies in library module, why do I have to add same dependencies in app module also? E.g., my library module is using edmodo android image cropper (https://github.com/ArthurHub/Android-Image-Cropper) for image cropping and in order to use that in app module, I had to add its dependency in app module also! Why? Can it be improved? Thanks in anticipation!

Comment: This is not a programming question. The reason is some how intuitive, whenever you want to use a library for security you allow those codes which both the person who will to share the library as module and the developer intended to use the library are agreed on to import it into developer's project. You would not allow it, so you disallow by making an app, otherwise a library to share the codes. Libraries are run only inside the apps, in other hand, libraries are passive and apps are active componenets

Comment: @matio So, in a layman language, it is something like: 
```
I have made one library module. It contains several other libraries as dependency and I might have paid for that and just because my library module can be shared or used by anyone, it doesn't mean anyone can get benefits of those paid libraries! So, if you want to use libraries those I have used in my library module, you will have to add it as a dependency in your project app module on your own and if it is not free, you will have to pay just as I might had to pay.
```
Is it so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> why do I have to add same dependencies in app module also?

This is because dependencies are not shipped along with your `.aar/.jar` file. The compile time binding exists, due to which your library compiles, but in order to have runtime implementation, you need to include those libraries in your app module.

> Can it be improved?

Can do that but ideally you should let the app module provide the dependencies. This is because, if two libraries ship with their dependencies, which could be used by both, then the common dependencies would be duplicated and overlap each other. This will cause build issues.

If you still want to proceed (may be you have internal module which is proprietary) then you can either extract the dependency libraries jar and include it in `libs` directory or publish it in maven along with the dependencies.

Comment: I have a similar situation, my .aar file has ML-Kit in it, and just as you said i added ML-kit in app module as well, but after that my apk size increased from 12 to 21 MBs, how can i avoid this?